# Using variables when calling sp_rename

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to make a stored proc which will

1. Drop a primary key
2. Rename the column name where the primary key was set
3. Create the new primary key

I'm struggling with the point number 2.

I'm trying to rename the column with `sp_rename` with the parameters passed to the stored proc like this:

```
EXEC sp_rename '[' + @SCHEMA + '].[' + @TABLE + '].[ID]' , 'Id', 'COLUMN'
```

But this way I got this error:

> Procedure or function 'sp_RENAME' expects parameter '@newname', which was not supplied.

How can I use `sp_rename` with parameters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this

```
DECLARE @SCHEMA NVARCHAR(30)='your schema name'
DECLARE @TABLE NVARCHAR(30)='table Name'
DECLARE @OLD NVARCHAR(30) = '[' + @SCHEMA + '].[' + @TABLE + '].[ID]'
EXEC sp_rename  @OLD, 'Id'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with `sp_rename`, per se, it's actually a problem with [`EXEC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

For each parameter you wish to pass, you may supply a *value* (a literal of some kind), a *variable* or the keyword `DEFAULT`. What you may not pass is an *expression* that computes a value.

```
[ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]  
    {   
      [ @return_status = ]  
      { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var }   
        [ [ @parameter = ] { value   
                           | @variable [ OUTPUT ]   
                           | [ DEFAULT ]   
                           }  
        ]  
      [ ,...n ]  
      [ WITH <execute_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
    }  
[;]
```

All this means that, if you wish to *compute* something, you need to do it as separate statement(s), and store the result of the computation in a variable, before the EXEC, as shown in [JaydipJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849348/15498).