# How to fix syntax error in sql column change with cursor?

Tags: sql, dbeaver, database-cursor

I want to change multiple column names but I'm getting a syntax error around the + in sp_rename and I don't know how to fix it. I've done so much googling already :(

This is the first part of my code.

```
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @newColumnName NVARCHAR(255);

DECLARE GlobalCursor CURSOR GLOBAL FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'XXXXXXXX' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'XXXXX%';

OPEN GlobalCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM GlobalCursor INTO @tableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @columnName = 'Prop_0';
    SET @newColumnName = 'dataset';
    EXECUTE sp_rename @tableName + '.' + @columnName, @newColumnName, 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: Try capturing the result of `@tableName + '.' + @columnName` in another variable, then use that in the sp_rename. It probably only understands variables, not expressions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849710/121309